# Golang decode map[string]float where float is encoded as string

Tags: json, go

So I'm dealing with an api that provides a json object that maps a string to a float, however, they encode the float as a string.

I know that you can use tags in the struct to say when an individual float is encoded as a string:

```
Item float64 `json:",string"`
```

I'm not necessarily *against* the idea of using an `interface{}` as the value in the map, but it just strikes me that there should be a way to do it.

Playground of example: http://play.golang.org/p/972hLoXbek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `json.Number`?
Example: http://play.golang.org/p/JiAA1HORuV
No idea if its the best way to do it though...

Comment: It'll do, at least more consistent than using strconv I feel.